# Java - Stuck after instantiating an object

Tags: java, loops, process, instance

I have a class, that needs to generate from time to time, a key and share it with a client and a server.

Kdc Class:

```
    protected Kdc() {
    (do stuff)
    runKdc();
} 


private void runKdc(){
    for(;;){
        generateKey();
        informClients();
        informServers();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(generationTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Sleep Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Kdc kdc = new Kdc();
    System.out.println("done"); //Doesn't reach the line
}
```

Now my problem is that i need to do something after starting the Kdc class and i can't! Because of the infinite loop, it just gets stuck in the Main class, after starting the Kdc class.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: show code of your  Kdc class.. Is it running in a seperate thread??. If not, then you are making the main thread sleep in the infinite loop. (I think you are not spawning a new thread to run your infinite loop)

Comment: Start the Kdc class in a new Thread, or creat a timer for executing `kdc.runKdc()`

Comment: why are you using this loop? never use such a loop!

Comment: @ZerO - he can use it. But he has to use a new thread. Such loops are common, how else would you expect a task to run over and over again?

Comment: Use a ScheduledExecutorService.  And find someone that knows Java.

Comment: @WhoAmI The more rational `while(true)` is indeed fairly common (e.g. a game loop, but it is a little untidy to end the program with a `break`. A `while(running)` is a little nicer where running is true until you want to quit

Comment: @RichardTingle - I completely agree :)

Comment: @RichardTingle Thank you for the advice. I will indeed change my loop :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other have said you should create the Kdc in it's own thread, for example

```
package com.testingarea;

class Kdc {

  public Kdc() {
    runKdc();
  }

  private void runKdc() {
    while(true) {
      System.out.println("Running kdc");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

}

class RunKdc implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Kdc k = new Kdc();      
  }

}

public class TestThread {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new RunKdc()).start();
    System.out.println("Kdc thread started");
  } 


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried with threads but i did `new Thread(new RunKdc()).run();` instead of .start().
Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should run your KDC in a sperate thread. This thread will run in the background, and your main method will proceed.

And for this loop:

```
while(true){
    //do something
}
```

is much better than your for(;;){} loop. Replace the "true" by a boolean variable like "running" or "active"

Comment: While I do agree with most of this; `Kdc` constructor will never exit, which just feels wrong to me. I'd prefer if `Kdc` didn't call `runKdc()` within its constructor (or if the thread was spun off within the constructor)

Answer (score 1):

Start the Kdc class in a new Thread, or creat a timer for executing `kdc.runKdc()`.
You can creat the instance in the new thread like in the example below, or only run the code of `runKdc()` in a new thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Thread keyGenerationThread= new Thread() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Kdc kdc = new Kdc();
        }
    };
    keyGenerationThread.start(); 
    System.out.println("done"); 
}
```